# TBody outline flashes on then off

Tags: html, html-table, outline

I have a html table within my asp.net page and I have applied the `<tbody>` tag around the two rows so I can outline the rows.

My HTML is as follows.

```
 <table>
                <tbody class="tableBody">
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">A Title</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="abc" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="def" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="ghi" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                <tbody class="tableBody">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">Another Title</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="jkl" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mno" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="pqr" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="stu" class="card"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
.AssetTableFormat {
    /*border-style: solid;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 10pt;

}

    .AssetTableFormat td {
        /*border:1px solid;*/
        padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

.card {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
}

.tableBody {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

When the page loads in IE 11 the outline appears after the content is shown but then it disappears.  If I try it in Chrome then the outline stays which is what I want.

EDIT:  I would add that the DIV's within the table cells are displaying a JavaScript gauge from [justGage](http://justgage.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `<tbody>` support in a single table is not fully (or at least, properly) supported under all circumstances in IE11

Newer browsers should handle it fine, which is why Chrome works as expected, and it will often work in IE11 too - but you'll find some weird behaviors in IE11 sometimes.

You may be able to fudge something using `tfoot` (or `thead`, but tfoot seems a better choice here), although beware of accessibility concerns around screen readers etc.